# OV7670: Why does the test pattern work, but the colors of a picture are wrong?

Tags: arduino, camera, fpga, yuv, ycbcr

I am working with the OV7670 camera module connected to an FPGA (Cyclone V DE0-CV board). When outputting the 8-bar color bar test pattern, everything is fine. To output the test pattern, register 0x71 is set to 0xB5.

[image: The 8-bar color bar test pattern.]

When trying to output an actual image, the colors are all wrong. The greyscale is fine, as can be seen below (I am not expecting higher quality from a module like this).

[image: The greyscale image.]

The colors are usually very pink-ish, and not many other colors are visible. This can be seen below. The resolution is not the issue, that is on purpose.

[image: The miscolored image.]

As the motive is clearly visible, this suggests that the Y-component of the YUV-data is correct, but that is not the case with the chrominance.

The motive of the image can be seen here to get a feel of what the colors should be.

[image: The actual motive of the image.]

The configurations I have played around with can be seen below. I have tried a lot of different combinations of these. configReg() sets a specified register (first parameter) to a specified value (second parameter).

```
configReg(0x12, 0x80); //Software reset, YUV

configReg(0x1E, 0x31);  //Flip image vertically
configReg(0x13, 0x81); //Auto gain enable, White balance enable, Auto exposure enable
configReg(0x3f, 0x01 ); //Edge enhancement factor 

configReg(0x70, 0x3A); // Enable pattern
configReg(0x71, 0x35 | 0x80); // Enable pattern

configReg(0x3A, 0x1D); // Fixed MANU, MANV
configReg(0x3D, 0x88 | 0x40); // UV saturation
```

Could it be a saturation problem due to the lighting? I am not misinterpreting the signals from the camera, as the test pattern is correct.

Answer (score -1):

[correct test pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEowU.png)
The test pattern is wrong. It should be like in the image attached.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30012525)